# Getting GPS time from TCP source + PPS device

Tags: ntp, clock, gps

I'm currently working on a Nvidia Jetson TX2 with Ubuntu 18, using an Emlid Reach GPS Module which is capable of provide NMEA messages through a TCP connection and a 1-PPS signal through a UART pin.

I'm not being able to correctly sync the system clock with the GPS clock.

I was able to compile the linux kernel with the required PPS flags:

```
CONFIG_PPS=y
CONFIG_PPS_DEBUG=y
CONFIG_PPS_CLIENT_KTIMER=y
CONFIG_PPS_CLIENT_LDISC=y
CONFIG_PPS_CLIENT_GPIO=y
```

Which exposes two devices: /dev/pps0 and /dev/pps1. pps0 corresponds to the kernel PPS and pps1 is a PPS related to a GPIO pin in the board.

The GPS module is connected with a USB cable but provides data by creating a USB-To-Ethernet interface and responding on IP 192.168.2.15, TCP port for data acquisition is configurable and set at 9001. The PPS signal is connected to a pin in the jetson.

My issue is that some gps/pps tools give me satisfactory results while others fail horribly.

Testing both pps signals:

```
 sudo ppstest /dev/pps0
 sudo ppstest /dev/pps1
```

Gives satisfactory results:

```
trying PPS source "/dev/pps0"
found PPS source "/dev/pps0"
ok, found 1 source(s), now start fetching data...
source 0 - assert 1657740302.347287559, sequence: 6590 - clear  0.000000000, sequence: 0
...
```

But the ppscheck tool doesn't and fails with:

```
$ sudo ppscheck /dev/pps0
# Seconds  nanoSecs   Signals
PPS ioctl(TIOCMIWAIT) failed: 25 Inappropriate ioctl for device
```

gpsmon is able to get the NMEA data from the TCP connection but not the PPS, with:

```
sudo gpsmon -D 5 192.168.2.15:9001:/dev/pps0
```

The PPS line remains blank.

On the other hand trying to configure gpsd fails with:

```
sudo gpsd -D 5 -N -n tcp://192.168.2.15:9001
gpsd:INFO: launching (Version 3.17)
gpsd:IO: opening IPv4 socket
gpsd:ERROR: can't bind to IPv4 port gpsd, Address already in use
gpsd:ERROR: maybe gpsd is already running!
```

Trying with pps1 gives analogous results.

Which would be the proper way to configure gpsd to take NMEA data from a TCP connection + a PPS device? Is there any documentation on that PPS "Inappropriate ioctl for device" error?

Thankss